# How to invoke a CMD file in JAVA correctly on windows?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I have sample java code like below.

```
    String testEfdDirectoryPath="D:\\test";
    String efdExecutable = "test.cmd";
    File executableFile = new File(testEfdDirectoryPath, efdExecutable);
    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder();
    $$pb.command("cmd.exe","/C",executableFile.toString());$$
    pb.directory(new File(testEfdDirectoryPath));
    Process p=pb.start();
    int code=p.waitFor();
    System.out.print(code);
```

In test.cmd there is actually a call to another java application. Unless I change the $$ marked line to the following to redirect its output, the another java app cannot be launched.

```
    pb.command("cmd.exe","/C",executableFile.toString(),">output.txt");
```

Do you guys have any ideas? Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your child process produce a lot of output (more than a few kilobytes)? If that is the case, you need to read that output from the process. You should try:

1. start the process
2. close the `stdin` of the process, so `pb.getOutputStream().close()`
3. repeatedly read from `pb.getInputStream()` and the error stream

This may be possible in one thread, or in multiple threads. Anyway, you should just take the explanation above as a list of keywords and try to search for an example code snippet that you can trust, preferrably from an Open Source application that does such a thing successfully.

Maybe http://commons.apache.org/exec/ can help you.

Comment: Thanks, Roland. You are right. I found this issue is stated in javadoc of ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Windows cannot execute scripts directly; when you double click on a .cmd file it actually opens the file in **cmd.exe**. So try `cmd.exe E:\\test\\test.cmd`.