# Not able to execute a cmd file in java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have to execute a `xyz.cmd` file which is in a directory `E:/abc`. So the absolute path of the file to be executed is `E:/abc/xyz.cmd`. When executed, a new window is created by the file itself.

My code snippet is:-

```
String path = “E:\\abc”;
String cmd = path + “\\xyz.cmd”;
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
processBuilder.directory(new File(path));
processBuilder.start();
```

This does not work, but gives no error or exception. But the cmd file works fine, it can be executed manually from its directory using explorer or cmd-prompt.
Tried using different versions of jdk, but in vain. I am using windows 7 OS. I do not see the process running in the Task Manager also.
Any idea what is going wrong? The same code works fine in a different computer with the same config.

===EDIT====
Can this be a security issue? Something like the user executing the program is not having enough priveleges to execute a file?

Comment: Where do you actually call cmd.exe? If you don't call cmd.exe how will the OS know what do with your xyz.cmd?

Comment: Hovercraft Full of Eels is correct: cmd files are not executable on their own, they actually require being passed as an argument to cmd.exe to be launched.

Comment: i need not, because the xyz.cmd file will take care of that. I am sure, because i have seen it running.

Comment: @gkris: then you are mistaken. cmd files will not run on their own and require that you explicitly call cmd.exe. A simple Google search would show you this. You have seen it running in the OS, not in Java -- big difference.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
but when i execute the xyz.cmd manually from windows explorer also, it works. The file has nothing but a call to another cmd file and set few system variables.

well this code is part of a sequence of calls which get executed in the cmd itself...so this doesnt require a cmd.exe as parameter.

Comment: @gkris: again, you're confused because you don't see what Windows Explorer is doing behind the scenes -- it is calling cmd.exe for you. Trust me, trust all of us -- you need to call cmd.exe.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: well i dont doubt your opinion, you are indeed correct. But try to understand, my environment is slightly different. One need not bother about cmd.exe, I am confident on this.

Well, if cmd.exe had to be added, then how will the same code execute properly in another system. I suspect some configuration issue.

Comment: Please read the second link in my answer -- the complete article. It's a little dated but is still *very* relevant.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels well for your saying i added the "cmd.exe" in the process builder, so it now looks as `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe",cmd);` 

but it does not help! :( There is no difference in the execution, xyz.cmd is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `cmd.exe` as first part of your process builder String in order for the command processor to be able to call the .cmd file. This is also true for .bat files, or any OS type command. For example, please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890414/how-to-invoke-a-cmd-file-in-java-correctly-on-windows).

Also, please look here: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

**Edit**
You state:

> please understand, this is not the problem of not adding cmd.exe in the processbuilder; because of the previous commands, cmd.exe will be taken care.

I see no documentation in your posts so far that this is true, and all my experience strongly suggests otherwise.

You also state:

> Can this be a security issue? Something like the user executing the program is not having enough priveleges to execute a file?

No way to know unless you capture and display the process's input stream. In fact if you don't capture this stream, you could prevent your process from functioning at all. Often we have to also capture the error stream as well, but you've combined them with

```
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true)
```

Please read my "When Runtime.exec() won't" link above for more on the necessity of capturing  streams.

Comment: +1, especially for the last link to the Java World article.  My view is that you should not be wondering why a `Process` fails until you have implemented *all* the recommendations.

Comment: please understand, this is not the problem of not adding cmd.exe in the processbuilder; because of the previous commands, cmd.exe will be taken care.